# fetch data from array and save it in database

Tags: mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I had this code

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

through which i got the following data

```
Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader Object
    (
        [sheets] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [maxrow] => 0
                        [maxcol] => 0
                        [numRows] => 2
                        [numCols] => 5
                        [cells] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [1] => sno
                                        [2] => candidta name
                                        [3] => email
                                        [4] => ctc
                                        [5] => location
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

I needed numCols so i used the following code

```
echo $data->sheets[0]['numCols'];
```

and got the result `5`

Now i wish to fetch the following values

```
[1] => sno                                     
[2] => candidta name
[3] => email
[4] => ctc
[5] => location
```

and store them in the table like this

```
id  value
1   sno
2   candidta name
3   email
4   ctc
5   location
```

Can anyone please tell how it can be done

Answer (score -1):

```
$Data = array();
foreach($data->sheets[0]['cells']['1'] as $key=>$value):
    $Data[] = "('".$key."','".$value."')";
endforeach;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_name(`id`,`value`) VALUES".implode(",",$Data)) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: This is not a coding service, can you explain your answer and perhaps cite sources?

Answer (score -1):

```
$newarray = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][1];
for ( $i=1; $i < count($newarray); $i++)
    { 
        echo $newarray[$i];

        $sql= "INSERT INTO `tablename` (value) VALUES ('$newarray[$i]')";
        if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                echo "Error: " . $sql. "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
            }  
    }
```

Comment: This is not a coding service, can you explain your answer and perhaps cite sources?